# What is self.instance in django?

Tags: django

What `self.instance` means in the code below?

```
Class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
interest_0 = forms.CharField(required=True)
interest_1 = forms.CharField(required=True)
interest_2 = forms.CharField(required=True)

def save(self):
    Profile = self.instance
    Profile.first_name = self.cleaned_data[“first_name”]
    Profile.last_name = self.cleaned_data[“last_name”]

    profile.interest_set.all().delete()
    For i in range(3):
       interest = self.cleaned_data[“interest_{}”.format(i]
       ProfileInterest.objects.create(
           profile=profile, interest=interest)
```

Here is a complete [code](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/).
I already read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265023/self-instance-in-django-modelform), but still, I can't understand their explanation. Can you explain in the easiest way possible?

Comment: The instance the form is *creating* or *editing*.

Answer (score 0):

The `.instance` attribute is the model object that the form is *constructing* or 8editing*. In this case it is (likely) a `Profile` object.

When you create a `ProfileForm`, you can pass an instance, like:

```
ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=some_profile)
```

If you do not pass a `instance=…` parameter, then the form will construct a *new* `Profile` object. If you thus save the instance, then it will thus create a corresponding record in the database.

Comment: What if i omit 'Profile = self.instance'? If I understood you right the 'Profile = self.instance' is just letting me do 'Profile.first_name = self.cleaned_data[“first_name”]
'.

Comment: @Darkhan10: then you assign the instance wrapped in the form to a local variable named `profile`.

Comment: What do you mean by ' the instance wrapped in the form'?

Comment: @Darkhan10: the instance the form is working on, the instance that is thus created, or edited.